# Unable to access the data from inside the For Loop from the outside of the For Loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scope

I'm unable to access the array data pushed to the variable declared outside of the `for loop`.

```js
        let tickets = [];                            

        (async () => {
          for (let chunk of chunks) {
            try {
              let ticketChunk = await someMethod(chunk)                
              tickets.push(...ticketChunk)   
              console.log("first log", tickets)
            } catch (error) {
              console.error(error)
            }
          }
        })();
        console.log("second log", tickets)
```

The above code shows the array in the `tickets` variable properly on the first log, but the second log shows empty.

Comment: it's an asynchronous function

Comment: because you don't wait the async function

Comment: Is `someMethod()` required to be called sequentially, or can it be called in parallel?

Comment: does `await` for `someMethod` stall for the result to arrive, `ticketChunk` in this case, only for the immediate following codes within the `try` block, but not outside?

Comment: @Kevvv It doesn't stall. If it did, it would be a synchronous, blocking function. `let ticketChunk = await someMethod(chunk); ...` is syntactic sugar for `Promise.resolve(someMethod(chunk)).then(ticketChunk => { ... })`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `chunks` and `ticketChunk` are both arrays, and that `someMethod()` is allowed to be called in parallel, here's a much simpler and faster approach using [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat):

```
Promise.all(
  chunks.map(async chunk => {
    try {
      const ticketChunk = await someMethod(chunk);
      // some other async functions...
      return ticketChunk;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      return [];
    }
  })
).then(ticketChunks => {
  const tickets = ticketChunks.flat();
  console.log(tickets);
});
```

---

If `chunks` or `ticketChunk` are not arrays, you can use [generator functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) to replicate the behavior above anyway:

```
function* map(iterable, callback) {
  for (const value of iterable) {
    yield callback(value);
  }
}

function isIterable(arg) {
  return typeof Object(arg)[Symbol.iterator] === 'function';
}

function* flat(iterable, depth = 1) {
  for (const value of iterable) {
    // value !== iterable prevents recursion on unit length strings
    if (depth > 0 && isIterable(value) && value !== iterable) {
      yield* flat(value, depth - 1);
    } else {
      yield value;
    }
  }
}

Promise.all(
  map(chunks, async chunk => {
    try {
      const ticketChunk = await someMethod(chunk);
      // some other async functions...
      return ticketChunk;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      return [];
    }
  })
).then(ticketChunks => {
  const tickets = [...flat(ticketChunks)];
  console.log(tickets);
});
```

Comment: If there was another async function that has to be executed using the array of tickets received from the the current `someMethod` we're discussing?

Answer (score 1):

because your "main" function is asynchronous

Try :

```
let tickets = [];
for (let chunk of chunks) {
  try {
    let ticketChunk = await someMethod(chunk)                
     tickets.push(...ticketChunk)   
     console.log("first log", tickets)
   } catch (error) {
     console.error(error)
   }
}
console.log("second log", tickets);
```

or

```
let tickets = [];
const someStuff = async() => {
  for (let chunk of chunks) {
    try {
      let ticketChunk = await someMethod(chunk)
      tickets.push(...ticketChunk)
      console.log("first log", tickets)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  }

}

await someStuff();
console.log("second log", tickets);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the async function that you have to execute before trying to handle the data that was loaded in it. That would look a little something like this:

```
let tickets = [];

(async () => {
    for (let chunk of chunks) {
        try {
            let ticketChunk = await someMethod(chunk)
            tickets.push(...ticketChunk)
            console.log("first log", tickets)
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error)
        }
    }
})().then(() => {
    console.log("second log", tickets)
});
```